# Oracle FLEXCUBE installer: WORK_AREA/TRACE_AREA directory is not available in Database

Tags: oracle, installation

At the installation process of Oracle Flexcube 14.5 / 14.6 by Oracle FLEXCUBE Universal Installer i`ve got the same error: "WORK_AREA/TRACE_AREA directory is not available in Database".

When i execute:

```
SELECT * FROM all_directories;
```

This Directories are present:

```
OWNER  DIRECTORY_NAME  DIRECTORY_PATH
SYS    WORK_AREA       /scratch/work_area/DEV/CTPW
SYS    TRACE_AREA      /scratch/work_area/DEV/FC122MAT/DEBUG
```

This Directories are also present at Database Server and writable for Oracle Database.
Platform: RHEL 8, Oracle Database 19.3 Enterprise.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the parameter in **CSTB_PARAM** using the below query.

```
 SELECT * FROM all_directories where directory_name in (select param_val 
 from CSTB_PARAM where param_name in ('WORK_AREA','TRACE_AREA'));
```

If there is no rows for the above select then you need to create directories with the below value

```
 select param_val 
 from CSTB_PARAM where param_name in ('WORK_AREA','TRACE_AREA');
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue like you during installation. eventhis Directories are also present at Database Server and writable for Oracle Database
"Oracle FLEXCUBE installer: `WORK_AREA/TRACE_AREA` directory is not available in Database"
I fix it by update parameter column param_val of CSTB_PARAM

```sql
update CSTB_PARAM  set param_val='WORK_AREA' where param_name='WORK_AREA';

update CSTB_PARAM  set param_val  set TRACE_AREA='TRACE_AREA' where param_name='TRACE_AREA';
commit;
```

Best regard,
Sovann